# Selenium junit test failing, driver taking URL too soon

Tags: java, selenium, driver

I am trying to get this test to pass.
I'm am checking if the webpage URL is equal to the expected URL.

However, the driver keeps taking the URL before the next page loads so it keeps checking the old URL with the expected one.

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("keywords")).sendKeys("Arlo Lamp");
    driver.findElement(By.className("search-form")).submit();
    
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ol[@class='product-list product-list-main']/li//a"))).click();
    
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println(url);
    assertEquals("https://www.dunnesstores.com/p/arlo-lamp/7761102?colour=Cream", url);
```

this should be the page that it is asserting

[image]

Instead, its the page before it clicks on the item that it keeps asserting

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either wait for that URL like this:

```java
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(webDriver -> webDriver.getCurrentUrl().equals("https://your.url"));
```

or wait for some UI element specific for that page.